# "INSERT INTO" doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-insert

I know there's couple of topics about why `INSERT INTO` doesn't work, but I didn't find any solutions for me.

So the problem is that I want to insert new record to my table.
The code is:

```
    $query = "INSERT INTO cms_galleryrsrc(_filename) VALUES ('$filename')";
    mysqli_query($db, $query);
```

MySQL table looks like:
`cms_galleryrsrc[_id (int, AUTOINCREMENT); _filename (varchar(255))]`

And it just doesn't do anythig...

Notice: for example `UPDATE`, `SELECT * FROM` works fine.
Please, help me :)

Comment: what LIMIT 1 doing in insert ?

Comment: You should try debugging, you'll most probably get an error message indicating what the problem is, and if it doesn't, you can still come on here with more info :-)

Comment: yeah, whats with the LIMIT 1 dude?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to delete it after testing `SELECT`, but it's still not working even without it

Comment: You should properly escape your input value with [mysqli_real_escape_string()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php), even better use prepared statements and bind your input to a parameter. What error message do you get.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While you have a limit that isn't technically needed in this instance, your code could be cut down to;

```
// Backtick is optional most of the time, it's personal preference for me.
$query = "INSERT INTO cms_galleryrsrc (`_filename`) VALUES ('$filename')";
mysqli_query($db, $query);
```

This leaves one final question; Have you confirmed $filename holds a value?

MySQL could be rejecting the query if `filename` doesn't allow null values, but $filename being blank gives it a null.

```
echo 'FN: ' . $filename;
exit;
```

above the query, then run and check output.

EDIT: After the reply from the OP, I checked the documents for MySQL and `_filename` is a reserved word.

Comment: I did what you suggested and it proved that `$filename` holds a value. But what I had to do to make my code works was to add backticks to `(_filename)` in my query.

Comment: I just checked the docs over at mysql and `_filename` is actually a reserved word, so without back ticks, it would have always failed. Thanks for letting me know so I could look into it :)

Comment: Great you checked it, well to know. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

After table name space is missing, try this it should work, & you don't need Limit clause

```
$query = "INSERT INTO cms_galleryrsrc (_filename) VALUES ('$filename')";
```

Comment: Actually it is the `limit 1` clause that he has that is causing the problem. Your code will work however :)

Comment: You are right Fluffeh, that's why why i didn't put it, i forgot to mentions

Answer (score 0):

You have a `limit 1` clause in your query which will cause MySQL to throw an error.

While it is possible to have a limit clause on an insert statement, the format you have won't work - you would have to have a query limited.

This following shows a simple insert with your code:

```
mysql> select * from test1;
+------+-------+
| id   | varry |
+------+-------+
|    1 | aaa   |
|    1 | NULL  |
+------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.03 sec)

mysql> insert into test1 values (2, 'ab') limit 1;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'limit
 1' at line 1
mysql> insert into test1 values (2, 'ab');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.07 sec)

mysql> insert into test1 values(2, 'ab');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
```